# TTFB very long first time you access the website

Tags: wordpress, performance, server, time-to-first-byte

I have an issue with a WordPress website I made: https://j-martini.com

Sometimes (generally the first time you access the website), the time before even HTML gets loaded can be very long (for example on this capture, 8s: https://postimg.cc/qgR0xqKm

I have no idea where the issue is coming from and since every time I test the website with tools such as GTmetrix I get a good result, I don't how to monitor the issue.

I contacted my hosting service, Scaleway, because I'm suspecting a slow server, but they're trying very bad to not help me at all. Even if it doesn't come for the server I kind of hoped that they could help me figure out where the problem is, but apparently not.

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Your site loaded quickly for me. It look 215ms to get the page HTML on my end. Have you considered using CloudFlare to serve the page assets and a cache plugin to cache the HTML?

Comment: Thx Daniel for your answer. Yes that's the weird thing, sometimes it loads super fast, sometimes not. That's why it's so hard to monitor. I already use a cache plugin, WP Rocket. Not considering a CDN yet since the loading of the assets doesn't seem to be the issue.